# How to output bullet type on comma separated value in sql

Tags: php, html, css, sql, codeigniter

I have a table structure like this.

```
| name       | data       | er         | fa_ma            |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| A          | B          | C          | Park,Lake,Walk   |
|-------------------------------------------------------- |
```

And I query my data like this

- Park,Lake,Walk

Using this code below

```
echo '<div class="additional-amenities">';
        echo '<span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> </span><strong>'.$row->fa_am.'</strong>';
```

But I want to query my fa_ma values into bullet type

like this:

- Park
- Lake
- Walk

*
Anyone can give a tip or help?
Thankyou!

Comment: You need output in separate rows?

Comment: use `explode()` after running query

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to query my fa_ma values into"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a loop. So you may explode the result into and array then loop on this array:

```
$r =  explode(",", $row->fa_am);

echo '<div class="additional-amenities">';
foreach($r as $i) {
    echo '<span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> <strong>'.$i.'</strong></span>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

You can also simply use `ul` like this :

```
$r =  explode(",", $row->fa_am);

echo '<ul class="additional-amenities">';
foreach($r as $i) {
    echo '<li class="available"><strong>'.$i.'</strong></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple you need to use **explode()** function of php and then use foreach loop to do that type of output.

```
$commadata = "Park,Lake,Walk"; or $row->fa_am;
$data =  explode(",", $commadata);

echo '<div class="additional-amenities">';
foreach($data  as $key => $d) {
echo '<span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> </span><strong>'.$d.'</strong>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Below code:

```
$myarr =  explode(",", $row->fa_am);

echo '<div class="additional-amenities"><ul>';
foreach($myarr  as $item) {
    echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul></div>';
```